# c# iterate through json

Tags: c#, json, soundcloud

Currently I am working on a soundcloud downloader in C#. With the help of the SoundCloud API I get a JSON string of a playlist, which includes a lot of information of the tracks:

http://pastebin.com/HfrjqyJE

I tried it with:

```
JObject results = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
foreach (var result in results["tracks"])
{
     string streamUrl = (string)result["stream_url"];
     string title = (string)result["title"];
}
```

it worked but it needs about 20 secs to iterate through a playlist with only 2 tracks. Is there a way to make this iteration process faster?

Comment: Are you sure the iteration takes 20 seconds and not the downloading?

Comment: yes because for downloading I have to press another button. I tested downloading a song with the streamurl and only took 2-3 secs for a song.

Comment: Why don't you create corresponding object structure of the json you get, and afterwards just deserialize it?

Comment: Have tried running it without debugger ? I've made sometimes the experience that it is versy slow if you have a debugger attached and / or compiled as debug (without optimizations). So measure the performacne with release build and without attaching a dbugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Newtonsoft JSON Deserializer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

For your case you could do something like this:

1. Create a Track class with needed properties
2. Apply DeserializeObject

   ```
   Track jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Track >(json);
   ```
3. Iterate over jsonObject

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps looping over the properties using JProperty, performs better?

```
    string json = "{a: 10, b: 'aaaaaa', c: 1502}";

    JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (JProperty property in parsedJson.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: [{0}], Value: [{1}].", property.Name, property.Value));
    }
```

Comment: He's not asking for clarity. He's asking for speed and why it takes 20 seconds.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to make sure this method does not perform better. Why ? I do not know.