# Iterate through JSON c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to iterate through the following json and needs to take out only name from the json. Can anyone help. I can't create any class because already same name properties are there in some other class.

```
{   "response": {
     "status": {
       "success": "true",
       "code": 200,
       "message": "SUCCESS"
     },
     "organization": {
       "custom_fields": [
         {
           "field": [
             {
               "name": "age_group",
               "label": "Age Group",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "String",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "birthday",
               "label": "Birthday",
               "type": "datepicker",
               "datatype": "String",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "comebackfor",
               "label": "comebackfor",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "customer_feedback",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "countries",
               "label": "countries",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "gender",
               "label": "Gender",
               "type": "select",
               "datatype": "String",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "{\"Male\":\"Male\",\"Female\":\"Female\"}",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "houseblockno",
               "label": "houseblockno",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "interest",
               "label": "interest",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "likeproducts",
               "label": "likeproducts",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "customer_feedback",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "maritalstatus",
               "label": "maritalstatus",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "nationality",
               "label": "nationality",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "occupation",
               "label": "occupation",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "pincode",
               "label": "Pincode",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "String",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "rateus",
               "label": "rateus",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "customer_feedback",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "salutation",
               "label": "salutation",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "service",
               "label": "service",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "customer_feedback",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "streetname",
               "label": "streetname",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "suggestions",
               "label": "suggestions",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "customer_feedback",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             },
             {
               "name": "unitno",
               "label": "unitno",
               "type": "text",
               "datatype": "Boolean",
               "default": "",
               "phase": "1",
               "position": "0",
               "rule": "",
               "regex": "",
               "error": "",
               "options": "",
               "scope": "loyalty_registration",
               "is_mandatory": "0",
               "is_updatable": "1",
               "is_disabled": "0",
               "disabled_at_server": "0"
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }   
   } 
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  Why can't you simply deserialize this into a class and get the values you want from that?  Newtonsoft's deserializer makes pretty trivial work of that.

Comment: Go here and paste your json here to have it generate your json to a class or you can do this straight from within Visual Studio as well  http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: json.net is your friend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# iterate through json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539656/c-sharp-iterate-through-json)

Answer (score -2):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) its something like:

```
var anon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(<YourStringHere>);
foreach(var item in anon.organisation.custom_fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
}
```

This will deserialise to an anonymous object, and allow you to iterate the contents as any other class would allow you to. You could also replace the foreach with a linq select.

```
anon.organisation.custom_fields.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Apologies if this isn't exactly right, without actually deserialising that json I can't be 100% sure what structure it will create.

Comment: This will create a JObject, but the `anon` variable is still defined as `object` - either way, you can't access the properties like that directly. You can use `dynamic`, or you can create a strong type.