# Get Property Value Only From Generic List Of Class C#

Tags: c#, list, class, generics

How can I read only values of each property of Generic List of Class type?

Let's say I have a class

```
  public  class Employee_tbt
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> JoinDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Salary { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Zip { get; set; }
}
```

And Filling List of class type from database

```
  List<DynamicClassName> genTbl = ConvertDataTable<DynamicClassName>(tbl);
```

**Note**

The class Name is change dynamically to fetch record of any table of any class in this case consider **DynamicClassName** = **Employee_tbt**

**Result:(2 Rows)**

```
{id:"1",Name:"abc",Designation:"xyz",Gender:"male",JoinDate:"1-1-2019",Salary:"333823",City:"bcw",State:"pak",Zip:"383"}


{id:"2",Name:"nn",Designation:"ww",Gender:"male",JoinDate:"1-1-2019",Salary:"389238",City:"akl",State:"lah",Zip:"400"}
```

Now I just want to read only property value of each row without mentioning property name.

**Expected Result:**

```
  {"2","nn","ww","male","1-1-2019","389238","akl","lah","400"}

  {"1","abc","xyz","male","1-1-2019","333823","bcw","pak","383"}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Your output isn´t clear ro me. Is this expected to be some JSON? So in your case just a `JArray` containing only the properties values.

Comment: Nothing immediate, but you could loop through all the properties and just build a string with the values. E.g : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31539858/442624